# How to sort rectangles in javascript according to the height

Tags: javascript, sorting, html5-canvas

I am looking for a program that sorts different size of rectangles in ascending order when space-bar is pressed.
I tried sorting but it gives the same results even after sorting.

This is what I've tried so far. I am using Brackets for coding in JS.
The code below is only for sorting, which is my major problem. Once, i get solution to it I can sort it with any key.

Please Help me out.

```
function C_ShapeRect(l_x,l_y,l_w,l_h,l_c)
{
    this.Xpos = l_x ;
    this.Ypos = l_y ;
    this.Width = l_w ;
    this.Height = l_h ;
    this.Color = l_c ;

    this.Draw = function m_drawRect(l_canvas,l_context)
    {
        l_context.fillStyle = this.Color ;
        l_context.fillRect(this.Xpos , this.Ypos , this.Width , this.Height);
    };
}

var g_RectArray  = new Array(5);
var g_RectArrayLength = g_RectArray.length ;
var g_RectWidth = 20 ;
var g_RectHeight = [35,20,77,10,50] ;
var g_RectColor = ["red","green","blue","yellow","black"] ;

function f_InitRectObject()
{
    var l_Xpos = 90;
    var l_Ypos = 175;

    for(var i=0 ; i<g_RectArrayLength ; i++)
    {
        g_RectArray[i] = new C_ShapeRect(l_Xpos,l_Ypos,g_RectWidth,-g_RectHeight[i],g_RectColor[i]);
        l_Xpos += g_RectWidth ;
    }
}
f_InitRectObject() ;

function f_DrawRectObject()
{
    for(var i=0 ; i<g_RectArrayLength ; i++)
    {
        g_RectArray[i].Draw(g_canvas,g_context);
    }
}

function f_clearCanvas()
{
    g_context.clearRect(0,0,g_canvas.width,g_canvas.height);
    g_context.strokeRect(0,0,g_canvas.width,g_canvas.height);
} 

var g_tempHeight = [] ;

function f_sortRect(l_array)
{
    for(var i=0 ; i<g_RectArrayLength ; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0 ; j < (g_RectArrayLength - 1) - i ; j++)
        {
            if(l_array[j] > l_array[j + 1])
            {
                g_tempHeight = l_array[j];
                l_array[j] = l_array[j+1];
                l_array[j+1] = g_tempHeight;
            }
        }
    }
}

function f_GameLoop()
{
    f_sortRect(g_RectArray) ;
    f_clearCanvas() ;
    f_DrawRectObject() ;
}
setInterval(f_GameLoop(),g_timeInterval) ;
```

Comment: `var g_RectArrayLength = g_RectArray.length ;`  --- is that line really worth it? A period isn't all that hard to type. In any event -- please give a [mcve], one which focuses on the core problem.

Comment: I have a feeling that it does work, but that you don't see the difference because the positions on the screen stay the same. That is, the first array element is now the smallest (with height 10), but it is still drawn in position 150,175.

Comment: Note you are invoking `f_GameLoop()` in setInterval when you should only be passing in the reference ...  `setInterval(f_GameLoop, g_timeInterval) ;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <html>
    <canvas width="300" height="300" id="myCanvas"> </canvas>
    <script>
        var g_canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var g_context = g_canvas.getContext("2d");

        var g_FPS = 30;
        var g_timeInterval = 1000/g_FPS ;

        var g_rectArray = new Array(10);
        var g_arrayLength =g_rectArray.length ;
        var g_rectWidth = 25;
        var g_rectHeight = [21,2,23,77,45,54,8,88,7,32];
        var g_rectColor = ["red" , "yellow" , "black" , "blue" , "cyan" , "pink" , "green" , "orange" , "brown" , "magenta"];

        var g_tempRectObj ;
//        var g_tempRectXpos ;
        var g_rectObjSortingIndex = 0;

        var g_startSorting =0;

        function C_Rectangles(l_x,l_y,l_w,l_h,l_c)
        {
            this.Xpos = l_x ;
            this.Ypos = l_y ;
            this.Width =l_w ;
            this.Height =l_h ;
            this.Color = l_c ;

            this.Speed  =1;
            this.directingSpeed  = this.Speed;

            this.targetRectXpos =0;
            this.targetCheck = 1 ;

            this.Draw = function m_drawRect(l_ctx)
            {
                l_ctx.fillStyle = this.Color ;
                l_ctx.fillRect(this.Xpos , this.Ypos , this.Width , -this.Height);
            } ;

            this.Move = function m_moveRect()
            {
                if(this.targetCheck == 0)
                    {
                        this.Xpos += this.Speed;
                        if(this.Xpos >= this.targetRectXpos && this.Speed > 0)
                        {
                            this.Xpos = this.targetRectXpos;
                            this.targetCheck = 1;
                        }

                        if(this.Xpos <= this.targetRectXpos && this.Speed < 0)
                        {
                            this.Xpos = this.targetRectXpos;
                            this.targetCheck = 1;
                        }
                    }
            } ;

            this.initMove = function f_initMove(l_targetPosition)
            {
                this.targetRectXpos = l_targetPosition ;
                if(this.Xpos < l_targetPosition)
                {
                    this.Speed = this.directingSpeed;
                }
                if(this.Xpos > l_targetPosition)
                {
                    this.Speed = -this.directingSpeed;
                }
                this.targetCheck = 0;
            } ;
        }

        function f_initRectObject()
        {
            var l_Xpos = 20;
            var l_Ypos = 200;

            for(var i=0 ; i<g_arrayLength ; i++)
                {
                    g_rectArray[i] = new C_Rectangles(l_Xpos,l_Ypos,g_rectWidth,g_rectHeight[i],g_rectColor[i]);
                    l_Xpos += g_rectWidth ;
                }
           console.log(g_rectArray);
        }

        function f_drawRectObject()
        {
            for(var i=0 ; i<g_arrayLength ; i++)
                {
                    g_rectArray[i].Draw(g_context);
                }
        }

        function f_moveRectObject()
        {
            for(var i=0 ; i<g_arrayLength ; i++)
                {
                    g_rectArray[i].Move();
                }
        }

        function f_rectObjectMovementCheck()
        {
            for(var i=0 ; i<g_arrayLength ; i++)
                {
                    if(g_rectArray[i].targetCheck == 0)
                        {
                            return true ;
                        }
                }
            return false ;
        }

        function f_clearCanvas()
        {
            g_context.clearRect(0,0,g_canvas.width,g_canvas.height);
            g_context.strokeRect(0,0,g_canvas.width,g_canvas.height);
        }

        function f_BubbleSort()
        {
            if(g_startSorting == 1)
            {
                if(f_rectObjectMovementCheck() == false)
                    {
                        if(g_rectArray[g_rectObjSortingIndex].Height > g_rectArray[g_rectObjSortingIndex+1].Height)
                            {
                                g_rectArray[g_rectObjSortingIndex].initMove(g_rectArray[g_rectObjSortingIndex+1].Xpos);
                                g_rectArray[g_rectObjSortingIndex+1].initMove(g_rectArray[g_rectObjSortingIndex].Xpos);

                                g_tempRectObj = g_rectArray[g_rectObjSortingIndex];
                                g_rectArray[g_rectObjSortingIndex] = g_rectArray[g_rectObjSortingIndex+1] ;
                                g_rectArray[g_rectObjSortingIndex+1] = g_tempRectObj ;
                            }
                        g_rectObjSortingIndex ++ ;

                        if(g_rectObjSortingIndex >= (g_arrayLength -1))
                            {
                                g_rectObjSortingIndex =0; 
                            }
                    }
            }
        }

        function f_GameLoop()
        {
            f_BubbleSort();
            f_moveRectObject();
            f_clearCanvas();
            f_drawRectObject();
        }

        f_initRectObject();

        function f_isKeyPressed(l_eventData)
        {
            if(l_eventData.keyCode == 32)
                {
                    g_startSorting = 1;
                }
        }

        setInterval(f_GameLoop,g_timeInterval);
        document.addEventListener("keydown" , f_isKeyPressed);
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could of course, always make use of the built-in array sorting functionality.
There's the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

And an example here:

```js
"use strict";

window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt)
{
    var g_RectArray = f_InitRectObject() ;
 console.log(g_RectArray);
 
 // copy the returned results
 var sorted = g_RectArray.slice(0);
 
 // and sort them
 sorted.sort( myCompareFunc );
 console.log( sorted );
}

function f_InitRectObject()
{
 var result = [];
 var l_Xpos = 90;
 var l_Ypos = 175;
    var g_RectWidth = 20 ;
    var g_RectHeight = [35,20,77,10,50] ;
    var g_RectColor = ["red","green","blue","yellow","black"] ;

 for(var i=0 ; i<5; i++)
 {
  result.push( new C_ShapeRect(l_Xpos,l_Ypos,g_RectWidth,-g_RectHeight[i],g_RectColor[i]));

  l_Xpos += g_RectWidth ;
 }
 return result;
}

function myCompareFunc(rectA, rectB)
{
 return rectB.Height - rectA.Height;
}

function C_ShapeRect(l_x,l_y,l_w,l_h,l_c)
{
 this.Xpos = l_x ;
 this.Ypos = l_y ;
 this.Width = l_w ;
 this.Height = l_h ;
 this.Color = l_c ;

 this.Draw = function m_drawRect(l_canvas,l_context)
 {
  l_context.fillStyle = this.Color ;
  l_context.fillRect(this.Xpos , this.Ypos , this.Width , this.Height);
 };
}
```

Comment: Yeah this can be done, but i am asked not to use this function. That's why i was thinking to use bubble sort, but couldn't figure out how to ?

Comment: @Marx - well then, why not duplicate the provided one then? Lets make a function to compare two elements, our 'compareFunc'. Next make a function that compares each element in the array with each element with a higher index. If the compare func says one thing, swap the two elements. If it says either of the other two things, do nothing. Have a close look at your sorting loop - the inner loop shouldn't start at 0, it should start at the element after the one currently pointed to by the outer loop. ;) You can write a sort function in 12 lines, 6 of which only have brackets on em...

Comment: Yeah ! that too work, but i did it in slight different manner.
Sorry, for delay in answer.